# How can I build Laravel relationships with model instances only?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am importing data using a file. The import does not create a set of single models, but rather a complex set of related models. I would like to show the user what *would* happen if they imported the dataset without actually storing anything in the database. I would like to send the model instances to my view as if it were imported.

I can build the complete set of attributes for the models and instantiate the model with those properties (`new Model($attributes)`), but can I also "load" a relationship manually with another model instance?

```php
$parent = new Parent($parentAttributes);
$related = new Related($relatedAttributes);

// Add $related to a $parent relationship so that I can access it from $parent somehow

dump($parent->related);
// This would output the same model as $related
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships` has a function called `setRelation` that gives this functionality.

```php
$parent = new Parent($parentAttributes);
$related = new Related($relatedAttributes);

$parent->setRelation('related', $related);

assertEquals($related, $parent->related); // true
```

This actually allows you to set arbitrary "relationships" and not based on actually defining the database relationship (e.g. having the `related()` relationship defined on the model). It uses the magic property that matches the key you used in `setRelation`.

```php
$parent = new Parent();
$model = new Model();

$parent->setRelation('arbitraryKey', $model);

assertEquals($model, $parent->arbitraryKey); // true
```